# Logging to SQLAlchemy logger in Pyramid app

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pylons

I have defined SQA logger in `development.ini` to log SQA queries to a separate file like this:

```
[handler_sqa]
class = FileHandler
args = ('%(here)s/log/sqlalchemy.log','a')
# "level = INFO" logs SQL queries.
# "level = DEBUG" logs SQL queries and results.
# "level = WARN" logs neither.  (Recommended for production systems.)
level = INFO
formatter = generic    


[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers = sqa
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine
propagate = 0
```

Now, it works, that is, SQA logs to that file only.

However, I would also like this specific logger to log additional messages to SQA log, i.e. to file `log/sqlalchemy.log`. I can get what seems to be the SQA logger like so:

```
sqa_log = logging.getLogger('logger_sqlalchemy')
```

However, it logs to main (that is `root`) logger instead..

How can I log additional messages to SQA logger instance instead of root logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger is is configured to handle anything with the prefix `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine`. Therefore you could make a new logger `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.foo')` but that would be poor practice I think to hijack the sqlalchemy namespace for your own purposes. Alternatively I think you should define a different logger that also shares the `sqa` handler.

```
[handler_sqa]
# all the same

[logger_myown]
handlers = sqa
propagate = 0
qualname = mysqa
```

You can grab that new logger via `logging.getLogger('mysqa')`.